# Render modal from nested component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

React beginner here.
I am trying to open a modal from a deep nested component that lives inside my "Homepage" component, without rendering my entire homepage component again.

My first thought was to use the context API, but as the state and also the context provider value changes, I am triggering a new render, and I can't allow that since the Homepage component is large.

What's the best approach on this scenarios?
Below is a screenshot of the code:

[image]

Comment: you should use Portals https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Raman. I got it working providing context to my nested component and using Portals for the modal placement.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same issue, I came up with this solution following Raman suggestion. Basically I created a context provider and wrapped my modal wrapper in it which is using a Portal. I don't know if this is the best or the most efficient solution, but it works.

[image]